# WSO2 get PDF from request

Tags: pdf, wso2, content-type, esb, wso2-esb

I need to get a pdf from a request to my WSO2 esb. This is my scenario:

**Request:**

```
CMS -- Request ----> wso2 ESB ----> backend
```

**Response:**

```
CMS <--- (PDF) --- wso2 ESB <--- PDF Byte Array --- backend
```

I think that I need to use something like 'aplication/pdf' but when I try to do it, my ESB throws a java error. The following is my code:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test" context="/test">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/myService">
      <inSequence>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="http://backendService/getPDF""></http>
                </endpoint>

            </call>

            <loopback/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <property name="messageType" value="application/pdf" scope="axis2"/>
            <property name="ContentType" value="application/pdf" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
            <send/> 
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence></faultSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Any idea?

**--- SOLUTION ---**

It was really easy and stupid, but I post my solution to avoid that someone waste time in the future:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test" context="/test">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/myService">
      <inSequence>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="http://backendService/getPDF""></http>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <faultSequence></faultSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

With this code I just returns the same request that I do to the server, so I get my PDFs files :D

Comment: How you save this file, where? You get it as base64?